# KeyError while dynamically filtering a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the following error in the subject line (please see screenshot attached for details) while trying to filter columns from a dataframe:

> None of [Index([''a','c''], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Here's my code:

```
seleted_columns_final = "'a','c'"

df_final = df[[str(seleted_columns_final)]]
print(df_final)
```

[image]

Test dataframe is as follows:

```
row1 = {'a':5,'b':6,'c':7,'d':'A'}
row2 = {'a':8,'b':9,'c':10,'d':'B'}
row3 = {'a':11,'b':12,'c':13,'d':'C'}
df = pd.DataFrame([row1,row2,row3])[enter image description here][2]
```

Comment: `seleted_columns_final = ['a', 'c']` `df_final = df[seleted_columns_final]`

Comment: I'm questioning why you have 2 strings, `'a'` and `'c'`, wrapped in a string, `"'a','c'"`, which you then call `str()` on again? @panktijk has the right way for this construction, but I think this may be an X<->Y problem. Your column names should be a _list_ of actual columnnames as strings, not as a single string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Pardon my ignorance, I just started with Python

Answer (score 0):

You have declared seleted_columns_final as a string ("'a', 'c'") and again converting it to string? I guess you want to make list of selected columns as a list and create a dataframe using that list.

Try:

```
seleted_columns_final= ['a','c']
df_final = df[seleted_columns_final]
print(df_final)
```

Output:

```
    a   c
0   5   7
1   8  10
2  11  13
```